# static block is not executed when i read one more field from file

Tags: java, static, static-block

I am reading some path from xml file in static block. I have read one field from xml file and it was succesful. When I try to read second element from the same file, static block is not executed.

```
    private static String path1 = "";
    private static String path2 = ""; 


static{
    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc  = docBuilder.parse("..."); // path of file



    Element element = doc.getDocumentElement(); 
    // if i open only this line, it works fine                  
    path1 = UtilityFunctions.getStringValue(element, "path1");

    // when i open this line all static block is not executed
    path2 = UtilityFunctions.getStringValue(element, "path2");  

}
```

Why static block is not executed when I add second line (path2 = ...) ?

Comment: What makes you think it's not executed?

Comment: It is executed ? may throw some exception ? U might have catch them ... please give little bit more information

Comment: I debuged it. Without second line it hangs on the breakpoint but when I add it does not.

Comment: Can you just add a System.out.println() ? It is pretty normal that debugger stops at a breakpoint : ) . It seemt to be a problem with UtilityFunctions.getStringValue() method, not static block invocation.

Comment: I just restarted to machine and it resolved, thank you for comments.